# session management for high traffic ASP.NET website.

Tags: asp.net, .net, session, high-availability, high-traffic

We use SQL server for our application's session state. Since the SQL server is a single point of failure, when it has problems it can affect all our customers. To mitigate this issue, we plan to create a SQL 2012 High availability instance and move .Net session management to its own servers. The SQL 2012 High availability instance can fail over automatically or manually when there are problems with a node. We are planning to use viprion to shard session state data across these lightweight AspState instances. Instead of using viprion to shard .Net session data at the webserver level, is there an alternate application level sharding approach that we can consider? This should be a common enough problem for high traffic ASP.Net sites that use .Net session management.

Comment: Try redis, it scalable, you can have distributed sessions, it mainly stores in memory, but for durability it stores them on disk based on some logic, when to store - http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-to-redis-in-memory-key-value-datastore

Comment: We tried to use Redis in one of our other highly used applications and we could not get it to work. Plus changing .Net session management from SQL server to Redis was too much of a risk. It was decided(by my higher-ups) that we should improve and use the .Net session management.

Comment: Using a hard drive based database for session management in a high traffic site makes no sense. If redis wasn't integrating well for you, use the Azure session state provider that sits on the azure cache. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg185668.aspx you'll get the maximum benefit if your site is in azure.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Marisic. I will check with my upper management if they would like to consider this. They generally frown on anything that is not in-house.

Comment: There's not much that's a clearer reason for the cloud to do it than a distributed in memory cache that is highly fault tolerant. I'm sure the costs will also be radically lower compared to standing up a new sql server too.

Comment: I accept your answer @Chris Marisic. Thanks.